# Symfony + Composer update dependency issues

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, sonata-admin

I'm running into issues trying to update my Symfony proj:

```
php composer.phar update
```

Which returns:

```
Problem 1
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony-cmf/symfony-cmf 1.0.0-alpha1
    - remove symfony-cmf/symfony-cmf 1.0.x-dev|keep symfony-cmf/symfony-cmf dev-master
    - symfony-cmf/symfony-cmf 1.0.0-alpha2 requires doctrine/phpcr-bundle 1.0.0-alpha4 -> satisfiable by doctrine/phpcr-bundle[1.0.0-alpha4].
    - symfony-cmf/symfony-cmf 1.0.x-dev requires doctrine/phpcr-bundle 1.0.0-alpha4 -> satisfiable by doctrine/phpcr-bundle[1.0.0-alpha4].
    - symfony-cmf/symfony-cmf dev-master requires doctrine/phpcr-bundle 1.0.0-alpha4 -> satisfiable by doctrine/phpcr-bundle[1.0.0-alpha4].
    - Conclusion: don't install doctrine/phpcr-bundle 1.0.0-alpha4|install symfony-cmf/symfony-cmf 1.0.0-alpha1
```

My composer.json is as follows:

```
   "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "symfony/symfony": "2.2.*",
        "doctrine/orm": "2.3.*",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "1.2.*",
        "twig/extensions": "1.0.*",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "2.1.*",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "2.2.*",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "2.2.*",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "2.2.*",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "2.2.*",
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "2.2.*",
        "jms/security-extra-bundle": "1.4.*",
        "jms/di-extra-bundle": "1.3.*",
        "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "*",
        "sonata-project/user-bundle": "dev-master",
        "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "2.2.*@dev",
        "sonata-project/easy-extends-bundle" : "dev-master",
        "sonata-project/intl-bundle": "dev-master",
        "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "2.2.*@dev",
        "sonata-project/cache-bundle": "dev-master",
        "knplabs/knp-menu-bundle": "1.1.x-dev",
        "sonata-project/block-bundle": "2.2.*@dev",
        "jackalope/jackalope-doctrine-dbal": "dev-master",
        "doctrine/phpcr-bundle": "1.0.*",
        "doctrine/phpcr-odm": "1.0.*",
        "symfony-cmf/routing": "1.1.*@dev",
        "symfony-cmf/routing-bundle": "1.1.*@dev",
        "symfony-cmf/symfony-cmf": "1.0.*",
        "symfony-cmf/create-bundle": "1.0.*",
        "sonata-project/doctrine-phpcr-admin-bundle": "1.0.*",
        "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "dev-master",
        "symfony-cmf/content-bundle": "dev-master",
        "slik/dompdf-bundle": "dev-master"


    },
```

I'm new to composer and can't really understand what is happening here.

Can you help?

**EDIT**
After applying jules suggestion I get this error

```
Problem 1
    - symfony-cmf/symfony-cmf dev-master requires symfony-cmf/block-bundle 1.0.0-alpha4 -> satisfiable by symfony-cmf/block-bundle[1.0.0-alpha4].
    - symfony-cmf/symfony-cmf dev-master requires symfony-cmf/block-bundle 1.0.0-alpha4 -> satisfiable by symfony-cmf/block-bundle[1.0.0-alpha4].
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony-cmf/block-bundle 1.0.0-alpha4
    - Installation request for symfony-cmf/symfony-cmf dev-master -> satisfiable by symfony-cmf/symfony-cmf[dev-master].
```

**Edit 2 - Symfony CMF older contents**

```
vendor/symphony-cmf/block-bundle
vendor/symphony-cmf/content-bundle
vendor/symphony-cmf/core-bundle
vendor/symphony-cmf/create-bundle
vendor/symphony-cmf/menu-bundle
vendor/symphony-cmf/routing
vendor/symphony-cmf/routing-bundle
vendor/symphony-cmf/symfony-cmf
vendor/symphony-cmf/tree-browser-bundle
```

All of these folders contain the expected (I think) structure inside Symfony/Cmf/Bundle/BundleName.

*The exception is the folder symfony-cmf which only contains docs.*

Does this help?

Comment: Thanks for you answer @jules. I've updated the question with the results of your suggestion. Any other idea?

Comment: I'm not sure, try to add `"symfony-cmf/block-bundle": dev-master"`

Comment: what happens if you throw out lines talking about things that are defined as dependencies by symfony-cmf/symfony-cmf ? would be routing and routing-bundle. and the block-bundle you added.

Comment: or try to remove deps until it works, to try to pinpoint what is the problem. did you try to rm -rf vendor/* to have composer re-install from scratch? sometimes it gets confused by installed versions. sonata is using sonata blocks and symfony cmf blocks is also based on soanta blocks. it needs the get the right versions of all those... you could try removing deps to narrow down the issue.

Comment: thanks for the reply @dbu. I did try to remove dependencies and remove the vendor folder and eventually composer installed all packages but at the end I'm getting "PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Symfony\Cmf\Bundle\CreateBundle\SymfonyCmfCreateBundle' not found". Any idea why?

Comment: Sure it installed symfony-cmf/create-bundle ?  What's in your Symfony\Cmf\Bundle\ dir?

Comment: I have updated the question to show the folder contents

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
php composer.phar update --prefer-dist
```